# How do I make the whole scene invisible, pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, python-3.6

I am trying to make a game where if someone press left-click, pygame draws a circle, then a line connecting the circle to the upper left corner. If he/she press right-click, it removes everything created from the screen. I thought about just covering everything with a big black square, but that is not really clearing the screen, just covering it. My code is as follow:

```py
    from pygame import * 
    init()
    size = width, height = 650, 650
    screen = display.set_mode(size)
    button = 0

    BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
    GREEN = (0, 255, 0)

    def drawScene(screen, button):
        # Draw circle if the left mouse button is down.
        if button==1:
            draw.circle(screen,GREEN,(mx,my), 10)
            draw.line(screen,GREEN, (0,0),(mx,my))
        if button == 3:
                mouse.set_visible(False)

        display.flip()


    running = True
    myClock = time.Clock()

    # Game Loop
    while running:
        for e in event.get():             # checks all events that happen
            if e.type == QUIT:
                running = False
            if e.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                mx, my = e.pos          
                button = e.button        


        drawScene(screen, button)
        myClock.tick(60)                     # waits long enough to have 60 fps

    quit()
```

Kindly guide me in this situation. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought about just covering everything with a big black square, but that is not really clearing the screen, just covering it.

There is not any difference between *cover* and *clear*. The screen consist of pixels. Drawing an object just changes the color of the pixels. Drawing a black square changes the color of the pixel again.

Note, operations like [`pygame.draw.circle()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.circle) and [`pygame.draw.line()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.line) do not create any object. They just change the colors of some pixels of the surface which is passed to the operation.

The easiest way to *clear* the entire window is [`pygame.Surface.fill()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.fill):

```py
screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
```

respectively

```py
screen.fill(BLACK)
```

Answer (score 0):

In computer graphics, there is no such thing as "clearing" a screen. you can only overwrite the previous drawing with new pixels. your idea of drawing a big black rectangle would work perfectly but I may be more efficient to use `screen.fill(0)`